# Cakephp 3 + CounterCache with prefixed plugin

Tags: cakephp-3.0

Let's assume we have two models:
Foo/Blog.posts and Foo/Blog.categories.

I want to update categories.post_count fields each time a new post is created.

I attached the CounterCache behavior in Foo\Blog\Model\Table\PostsTable like this (in my initialize func):

```
$this->addBehavior('CounterCache', [
   'Categories' => ['post_count']
]);
```

But when I try to add a new post, I have an error like this:

```
Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'my-db.categories' doesn't exist
```

Any idea?
Tx for your help

Answer (score 0):

I found what it doesn't work.

My relationships between Foo/Blog.posts and Foo/Blog.categories was incorrect. I forgot the plugin prefix.

The correct relationships declaration:

```
$this->belongsTo('Categories', [
    'className' => 'Foo/Blog.Categories'
]);
```